# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails YII2

Tags: yii2

Deleting items from database failing and returns "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails" Yii.

deleteAction:

```
 public function run($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($this->checkAccess) {
        call_user_func($this->checkAccess, $this->id, $model);
    }

    if ($model->delete() === false) {
        throw new ServerErrorHttpException('Failed to delete the object for unknown reason.');
    }

    Yii::$app->getResponse()->setStatusCode(204);
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that there are constraints on this record.
For example you have

table: user
   id as primary key

with a constraint to

table: profile
   user_id -> user.id

this prevents it from deleting.

You would have to delete the related records first like:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    // delete profile first to handle foreign key constraint
    $user = $this->findModel($id);
    $profile = $user->profile;
    $profile->delete();
    $user->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```